# Next Post Link Parent Category and sort by Title WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

using that for next link in that decided taxonomy. but its not getting next item by title.

in my WordPress have multiple categories and sub categories. need to work that as parent category. and should be sort by title.

```
next_post_link('%link', '<h5>LINK</h5>', TRUE, '', 'portfolio-category');
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you want.